# How to recover bitcoin from a site that is no longer operating?

Tags: lost-bitcoins, lost-wallet

In 2013 I had 1.5 but coins on bitinstant. The bitcoin lost money and it was at 73$. Since it was hard to deal with I let it go. I don’t even care to get it out for less than 150$

But now it’s skyrocketed.
The site is shut down though. 
Is there anything I can do to find it?

Comment: Please do not use obscenities in your posts. I've removed it for you. Note that other users may have flagged your post as "rude or abusive" leading to possible rep loss or suspension. Please read [Be Nice](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/help/be-nice): "Avoid vulgar terms and anything sexually suggestive"

Comment: I’m so sorry !!! I’m trying to edit the post, but I can’t seem to figure out where.

Comment: I've already proposed an edit. It is waiting for approval.

Comment: You might have made a backup of your wallet and stored that on your drive. It may contain a private key...

Comment: If you don't own the private key, you don't own the coins. As sad as this is, you will have to accept the coins are lost.  This is a very common occurrence and many of us have similar stories. Always use a offline wallet and back up your private keys!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as its a matter between you and bitinstant (now, I believe would be a matter with the Department of Justice, USA). I'm sorry for your lost.